# WHM Language Changed to German

Tags: server, admin, cpanel, whm

Hoping someone can help with this..

For some reason the default language in WHM is now German, instead of English.

I checked:

```
Home »Server Configuration »Tweak Settings
```

and the default language in English, however all of the icons are German and the sidebar text is German.

Any idea how this could happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you provide more information.

Have you installed any third-party applications such as RVSkin?

Note that a language can also be selected before logging into Web Host Manager, with a selection of languages below the login box.

You can also try deleting the german langauge from locale
/var/cpanel/locale/

Comment: Thank you!  It seems that I somehow selected German and the page bookmark was saved that way.  So all I had to do was select English from the login page.  It feel a bit silly, but relieved..  Thank you